# adobe flex app located in div

Tags: css, apache-flex, layout, adobe

I have a Flex 4 app, which is in a full-window mode now.

Is it possible to place window of my Flex app just in the special `div` with fixed size (for example 400x400px)?

Comment: What is a "full window mode"?  And how did you put your Flex app in it?  You should be able to embed any SWF inside a div with a specific size the same way you embed the Flex app in any HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Flash Builder, you can modify the page in your html-template folder to fit the size you want.

If that has more cruft than you want, look into using [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).